# How can I tell VIFM to filter binary files, ".hi" files and ".o" files?

Tags: regex, vifm

I've managed to filter ".hi" and ".o" with:

```
:filter '\.(o|hi)$'
```

But how do I filter binary files too?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please edit your [question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to include what research you've done on your own in attempt to answer your question.  Tell us what you've tried so far and specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: The question is pretty straightforward. I'm not "stuck" anywhere, it clearly says what I need. I've read the whole VIFM manual and couldn't find any obvious way to do it. I've asked on freenode and nobody could answer. That is what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. It's *file name* filter and names do not suggest whether file content is binary or not.

There are basically two possible ways to implement this:

- query mime-type of each file
- examine content of each file to evaluate its kind

Both options involve reading files, and that's something you don't really want to do as it can kill performance (look at file managers that display file previews, they are quite slow even in the presence of caches). For the second option something like first 512 bytes would be enough, still if you open directory containing 1000 files (`/usr/bin`, for example) all those files should be located on your storage, which is very slow unless they are already cached by your OS kernel.